# Mysql Query to remove unwanted letters from the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql table in which one column named 'city' is like below :

```
 id      city

 1       New Jersey(Trenton)

 2       New Jersey(Burlington)

 3       New Jersey(Cherry Hill)

 4       New York(Manhattan)

 5       Philadalphia(BalaCynwd)
```

So what query can i put in the phpmyadmin so that i can remove the name in the  bracket? So i am looking for a result in which i get only city and not bracket. So it wil be New Jersey, New York and Philadelphia.. I have 3 million rows so i cannot do it manually.

So can i put like below?:

if 'city' = '%New Jersey%' then set 'city' = 'New Jersey'; ?
but this even if it works ...i will have to execute lots of queries for all cities..

Thanks

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/1741542 is of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET city=SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, '(', 1)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index for details.

Comment: +1 Although this won't work, when there are additional words after the braces.

Comment: @OlafDietsche you're right since this only takes the first substring before delimiter. This only works when his column values just like what in his question above.

Comment: I am just making a backup and will try @OlafDietsche query soon...thanks

Comment: I tried this UPDATE `jos_jbjobs_jobseeker` SET 'city' = SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, '(', 1);  and I get an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''city' = SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, '(', 1)' at line 1

Comment: @ricardo just remove quotes from `'city'`. `UPDATE jos_jbjobs_jobseeker SET city = SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, '(', 1)`

Comment: yep thank@SubRed DONE !! I put SELECT DISTINCT city from the table and i got the result which i wanted..many thanks to you and Merry Christmas.